# How to install GNOME 3 on RHEL6?

Tags: rhel, gnome, gui, desktop

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, it has Gnome GUI, but it is very simple and  not like Ubuntu's GUI.

I want to install/upgrade my GNOME Desktop Environment to its latest release.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6):

You have two choices:

1. Wait for RHEL7 later this year, it will be based on versions of Fedora that contained gnome3 and systemd.
2. Compile everything from source.

Those are basically it. Even [CentOS](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-devel/2013-January/008999.html) says they won't do it since it involves re-compiling too much original code. Not to mention it would be an enormous amount of work for marginal benefit.

I'll also add that once you get passed a certain point, you'll end up in the terminal more times than not, so the DE basically becomes the thing you launch gnome-terminal and Firefox sessions from.